# Getting an error message: "Unhandled Lockdown error (-3)" when trying to mount iPhone SE to Linux Debian

Tags: debian, iphone

I'm trying to connect an iPhone SE with iOS 11 to a Linux Debian 9.4 "Stretch" desktop with XFCE environment. I followed step-by-step about 5 different guides on the internet how to do so. I ended-up installing the packages: `libimobiledevice` `ideviceinstaller` and attempted to use their functionality however with no success.

I tried to mount my iPhone using both: `idevicepair pair` which replies with `SUCCESS` after trusting the computer, however when trying to actually access the device an error message will pop up citing:

> Failed to mount "Documents on (my name)'s iPhone"
>   **Unhandled Lockdown error (-3)**

I tried another approach by using `ifuse` to mount my iPhone to a local directory, but it didn't work either. It replies with an error message within the terminal citing:

> Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device. Try again. If it
>   still fails try rebooting your device.

I tried to reboot my device, however it did not work at all.
I also deleted the lockdown files according to another troubleshooting guide but it didn't work either, `idevicepair` just created new files which again resulted in this device lockdown error.

I to connect my iPhone to my desktop.

Comment: Is your phone unloked when you try to mount it?

Comment: Unlocked in what sense? as in user PIN code? Oh yes, I didn't set one. It's also trusting my computer.

Comment: Android phones are blocked and you need pattern/pin/fingerprint to unlock them, if they are locked then you can't mount them, that was the reason for the question.

Comment: See the [debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/iPhone) : Configure the iPhone part and the mount-iphone.sh script

Comment: @GAD3R, I used that guide and it says that mount-iphone.sh is not needed if you have a newer Debian version than Wheezy (which is Debian 7.0?) so I actually skipped it. It cites "If you are running Wheezy or later, the following happens automatically, and you can skip to the next section. ". Should I insist on running the mount-iphone.sh anyway?

Comment: @YoMismo, Well then in that case my iPhone is being definitely unlocked. I don't use fingerprint/PIN or a pattern to lock it. It asked me to trust my computer and I confirmed it. Beyond that Linux seems to claim that there's a lockdown, but I can't figure out which or what kind of lockdown is it.

Comment: @GAD3R, I just tried to run the mount-iphone.sh script, however it doesn't work, it yields exactly the same error message as with idevicepair: "Error mounting location: Unhandled Lockdown error (-3), iphone mount failed"

Comment: Linux(Ubuntu+Mint)are currently working on the support of IOS devices on all platforms (Debian,Cinnamon,KDE ext...) It will be ready soon. Be patient!! For now try: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6s-ios-11.html kind regards
I.S

Answer (score -1):

Everybody with this problem might have to get some latest libraries. On Debian this could mean that you have to download the sources an compile them on your machine by yourself. I recomment to try the recipe of Sam Rocketman:
https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc
In my case it solved the issue.